# Не запускается Webdriver Chrome Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, selenium, selenium-webdriver

При попытке вызова webdriver в питоне в WSL выдаёт следующую ошибку. Как это лечить

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
capabilites = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, desired_capabilities=capabilites)


<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 106, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 288, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 381, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x7f87bdd43563 <unknown>
#1 0x7f87bdb02667 <unknown>
#2 0x7f87bdb2abb7 <unknown>
#3 0x7f87bdb26d90 <unknown>
#4 0x7f87bdb676b7 <unknown>
#5 0x7f87bdb6705f <unknown>
#6 0x7f87bdb5eef3 <unknown>
#7 0x7f87bdb3249e <unknown>
#8 0x7f87bdb335ae <unknown>
#9 0x7f87bdd92fde <unknown>
#10 0x7f87bdd964c4 <unknown>
#11 0x7f87bdd7978e <unknown>
#12 0x7f87bdd97393 <unknown>
#13 0x7f87bdd6c665 <unknown>
#14 0x7f87bddb8108 <unknown>
#15 0x7f87bddb8296 <unknown>
#16 0x7f87bddd3183 <unknown>
#17 0x7f87bd665609 <unknown>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t

Comment: (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)